# store positive number and negative in different vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to c++. I have a vector with size n. I want to search in the vector ad store positive and negative values in the new vectors. I don't know the number of positive and negative values.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The basic solution here is simple if you know the language, so can you please try to be more specific about what part your are struggling with and/or what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show us what you have already done

Comment: Why do you feel this requires a vector based solution?

Comment: @Craig I would imagine he thinks it's solved with vectors because he states `I dont know the number of positive and negative values`

Comment: @Craig: Do you see some particular reason to believe another possibility would be superior, or are you just being contrary?

Comment: So, what do you want to do with `0`?

Comment: I was merely asking since the opening statement was "I am new in C++".  I wanted to ascertain if the vector was through choice or imposed.  Out of interest, I now wonder whether there is less overhead in creating two 32k (assuming a 32bit system) arrays or two vectors.  Obviously, this is a performance vs. memory consumption question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `v` being your `std::vector<int>` vector and `0` being positive, you just need to loop over the vector and store positive numbers in one vector and negative numbers in the other:

```
using std::vector;
vector<int> pos, neg;

for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.cbegin(); it != v.cend(); it++) {
    if ((*it) >= 0) pos.push_back((*it));
    else neg.push_back((*it));
}
```

A `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` is used here because you do not need to modify the original vector in any sense, you are just *reading* its values.

Comment: @H'H Tell me, what was so hard with this problem/solution? Seriously, I'm interested in what's **not** obvious. The check for a number being positive or negative? Or what? (maybe the iterators, but then you revert back to size and subscripting, or horribile dictu, you read the documentation...)

Comment: @H2CO3 as i said am new in c++, i did not know about the this iterator and push_back....sorry that am not as expert as you guys and i ask some obvious question....

Comment: @H'H, the point here is that you didn't know because you didn't read the documentation, not because you are new to C++. :)

Comment: @H'H Again -- if you don't know about iterators as a beginner, that's not a problem. You will read about them later. But honestly, couldn't you come up with the idea to iterate through the vector and select the elements based on if they are negative or positive? It's a very simple, very obvious solution, it doesn't require any C++ knowledge just a bit of common sense.

Answer (score 11):

Here is yet another solution using [std::partition_copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) from the standard library:

```
std::vector<int> src, neg, pos;

std::partition_copy(
    src.begin(), src.end(),
    back_inserter(neg),
    back_inserter(pos),
    [](int value){ return value < 0; }
);
```

Comment: This is getting even better.

Comment: I cannot help but +1 this. Not because I think it's a good solution but because I just discovered `partition_copy` :D

Comment: Definitely +1 *because* it is a good solution. Though I should add a note that this function was introduced with C++11 (but so was the lambda that the answer uses, anyway).

Answer (score 3):

If you can rearrange items in your source vector, it's probably easiest to do something like this:

```
auto part = std::partition(input.begin(), input.end(), [](int p) { return p < 0; });

std::vector<int> neg(input.begin(), part);
std::vector<int> pos(part, input.end());
```

Comment: Nice, although OP might be surprised to find `0` in the positive integers container :)

Comment: Very neat solution, indeed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: He might. Since he didn't say what to do with zeros, I guessed he really meant negative and non-negative numbers (though I probably should have stated that explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @Shos's answer, involving less pointers, which might be easier to read:

```
using std::vector;
vector<int> pos, neg;

for (auto& el : v) 
{
    if (el >= 0) 
        pos.push_back(el);
    else 
        neg.push_back(el);
}
```